# Calculate percentage by using column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I got a table with the below data in it.

[image]

all I need to do is a query the calculate 10% of the damage so I have done the below:

```
 SELECT damage = (damage * 10) /100 
        ,[Peril_Code]
         FROM [LocExposure].[dbo].[myTable]
```

and this return the below result:

[image]

[Damage] column is a float .

I cannot figure out why it returns the wrong calculation.

Comment: In what way do you think this output is incorrect?

Comment: for example looking at the second record I was expecting 0.0000125444785042888 not 1.25444785042888E-05 I think it is just a format issue

Comment: just found out that it was a formatting issue (scientific notation). I have modify the query casting the resul as decimal using the maximum number for the precision and now it looks good:
convert(decimal(30,18) , damage * 10 /100 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is correct. No error. Please check the result `2.44E-06` where your actual value was `2.44E-05`.

So, there is no error.

**UPDATE:**

For avoiding scientific notation, you can go through the following post

[convert float into varchar in SQL server without scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521354/convert-float-into-varchar-in-sql-server-without-scientific-notation)

Comment: look at the second record I was expecting 10% of 0.000125444785042888 which is not 1.25444785042888E-05

Comment: `0.000125444785042888` is `1.25444785042888E-04` So `10%` of `0.000125444785042888` is `1.25444785042888E-05` which is right. I don't see any error

Comment: probably is just a format issue. I want all the appear with no E-04,E-05 etc

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso: Yes, this is just formatting but it has no error!!

Comment: yes it is just a formatting issue I have fixed it casting to a decimal please look at my comment

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Damage TABLE
(
        Damage      FLOAT,
        PerilCode   CHAR(1)
)
INSERT INTO @Damage VALUES
        (2.44253351044103E-05   , 'T'),
        (0.000125444785042888   , 'T'),
        (0.00015258112714104    , 'T'),
        (0.000238995871781784   , 'T'),
        (0.000267978447740977   , 'T')

SELECT  Damage, Damage * 0.1 [10%], PerilCode
FROM    @Damage
```

Output

```
Damage                  10%                 PerilCode
---------------------------------------------------------
2,44253351044103E-05    2,44253351044103E-06    T
0,000125444785042888    1,25444785042888E-05    T
0,00015258112714104     1,5258112714104E-05     T
0,000238995871781784    2,38995871781784E-05    T
0,000267978447740977    2,67978447740977E-05    T
```