# SQL Server Express 2008r2-sp2 outer join based on 3 common fields: issues with duplicating common fields and FLOAT->NVARCHAR conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates, outer-join

I have a question about **joining data** from two permanent tables in the same SQL Server Express 2008-r2 sp2 database into a third permanent table in the same database.

Rows in tables need to be joined **on a condition if data in three fields common to these tables match**.

The first table contains no duplicates (and has no primary key), however there can be more than one row where 3 common fields match. The second tables does contain some duplicates, however they cannot be removed because they are consistent with the business logic of the table; the end-user of a third (joined) table needs to see if three common columns have more than one occurrence in any of the source tables, and if positive, to make further inquires whether duplicates are data quality error or they represent parts of the same transaction booked with identical entries in the source data.

Below I present simplified layout of two source tables, common fields to both tables are marked with *:
**Table_1**
[image: Table_1]

**Table_2**
[image: Table_2]
<sub>(source: [bildites.lv](https://www.bildites.lv/images/z3fmkk82u5c4lrb3n7lw.jpg))</sub>

The resulting (joined) table (**Table_3**) should look like this:
[image: T3]
<sub>(source: [bildites.lv](https://www.bildites.lv/images/ap613hdp90nri5125lg.jpg))</sub>

Field `Dup_1` denotes the number of times the same combination of common fields B*, C* and D* is repeated in Table_1. `Dup_2` does the same for Table_2. It does not take into account whether these rows are complete duplicates or not, only whether the particular table has duplicate combination of common fields B*, C* and D*.

In case of duplicating common fields, it does not matter which row from Table_1 is joined with which row from Table_2 (indeterminate is ok) - for example, both [A2-B2-C2-D2-E2-F2-G2] and [A3-B2-C2-D2-E3-F4-G4]would be ok as the resulting joined row in Table 3. The end user will see the number the common fields match in each of the source tables (Dup_1 and Dup_2) and take appropriate further action.

**The steps I have taken so far:**
I tried to see if I can add the field Dup_1 to the Table 1.
At first I tried to construct new field, which is concatenation of fields B*,C* and D*:

```
SELECT Field_A, 
   COALESCE(CAST(Field_B* as NVARCHAR(30)), '') + 
   COALESCE(CAST(Field_C* as NVARCHAR(30)), '') + 
   COALESCE(CAST(Field_D* as NVARCHAR(12)), ''),
   Field_E,
   COUNT(COALESCE(CAST(Field_B* as NVARCHAR(30)), '') + 
   COALESCE(CAST(Field_C* as NVARCHAR(30)), '') + 
   COALESCE(CAST(Field_D* as NVARCHAR(12)), ''))

FROM Table_1
    
GROUP BY COALESCE(CAST(Field_B* as NVARCHAR(30)), '') + 
         COALESCE(CAST(Field_C* as NVARCHAR(30)), '') + 
         COALESCE(CAST(Field_D* as NVARCHAR(12)), ''));
```

This gave me nice results (i.e." B1C1D1" or "B9D9", where C9 is NULL, and number of duplicate field combinations), **except the problem with Field_C**. Entries in this field are all standard format long ID numbers, i.e. 2300034586839938373. They are imported into Table 1 from excel file via Openrowset, ACE and JET OLEDB drivers (depending on Excel file format). The only way to import them correctly (not to get scientific notion, i.e. 1.08E+05) is to import them as FLOAT variables. However, when I CAST them as NVARCHAR, they are formatted back to scientific notion, and this creates a problem, as **for the same Field_C* entry expressed as NVARCHAR (scientific notion), various slightly different ID numbers (expressed as FLOAT) can correspond**, thus Dup_1 will be in some cases overestimated and some joined entries in Table 3 will be missing.

**UPDATE 1:**
Below I add T-SQL code to create above-mentioned tables Table 1 and Table 2 with data in Fields B, C and D that is similar to real data in my problem:

```
-- Instead of "JoinTest1" use the name of your testing database
USE JoinTest1;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Join1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.Join1;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Join1
(
[Field_A]   NVARCHAR(2),
[Field_B]   FLOAT(24),
[Field_C]   FLOAT(53),
[Field_D]   DATE, 
[Field_E]   NVARCHAR(2)
);
GO

EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Join1
VALUES (N''A1'', 111.1111, 32822040701 ,''2002-02-01'', N''E1''),
(N''A2'', 222.2222, 32822040702 ,''2002-02-02'', N''E2''),
(N''A3'', 222.2222, 32822040702 ,''2002-02-02'', N''E3''),
(N''A4'', 222.2222, 32822040704 ,''2002-02-02'', N''E4''),
(N''A5'', 555.5555, 32822040705 ,''2002-02-05'', N''E5'')')


IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Join2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.Join2;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Join2
(
[Field_F]   NVARCHAR(2),
[Field_B]   FLOAT(24),
[Field_C]   FLOAT(53),
[Field_D]   DATE, 
[Field_G]   NVARCHAR(2)
);
GO

EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Join2
VALUES (N''F1'', 111.1111, 32822040701 ,''2002-02-01'', N''G1''),
(N''F2'', 222.2222, 32822040702 ,''2002-02-02'', N''G2''),
(N''F3'', 222.2222, 32822040702 ,''2002-02-02'', N''G3''),
(N''F4'', 222.2222, 32822040702 ,''2002-02-02'', N''G4''),
(N''F5'', 222.2222, 32822040704 ,''2002-02-02'', N''G5''),
(N''F5'', 222.2222, 32822040704 ,''2002-02-02'', N''G5''),
(N''F6'', 666.6666, 32822040706 ,''2002-02-06'', N''G6'')')
```

For illustration purposes I also post the code that creates Table 3 - my desired end result after joining tables 1 and 2:

```
-- Instead of "JoinTest1" use the name of your testing database
USE JoinTest1;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Join3', 'U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE dbo.Join3;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Join3
(
[Field_A]   NVARCHAR(2),
[Field_B]   FLOAT(24),
[Field_C]   FLOAT(53),
[Field_D]   DATE, 
[Field_E]   NVARCHAR(2),
[Field_F]   NVARCHAR(2),
[Field_G]   NVARCHAR(2),
[Dup_1]     SMALLINT,
[Dup_2]     SMALLINT
);
GO

EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Join3
VALUES (N''A1'', 111.1111, 32822040701 ,''2002-02-01'', N''E1'', N''F1'', N''G1'', 1, 1),
(N''A2'', 222.2222, 32822040702 ,''2002-02-02'', N''E2'', N''F2'', N''G2'', 2, 3),
(N''A4'', 222.2222, 32822040704 ,''2002-02-02'', N''E4'', N''F5'', N''G5'', 1, 2),
(N''A5'', 555.5555, 32822040705 ,''2002-02-05'', N''E5'', NULL, NULL, 1, NULL),
(NULL, 666.6666, 32822040706 ,''2002-02-06'', NULL, N''F6'', N''G6'', NULL, 1)')
```

Finally, I have managed to add the correct string data type column to Table 1 (see code below), therefore FLOAT->NVARCHAR conversion is no longer an issue. Next step is to find a way how to use GROUP BY on this new column [3ColStr] in Table 1 in order to obtain [Dup_1] column, and then do the same procedure for Table 2, before trying to join them together.

```
-- Instead of "JoinTest1" use the name of your testing database
USE JoinTest1;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Join1
ADD [3ColStr] AS 
(COALESCE(CAST([Field_B] as NVARCHAR(12)), '') +
COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),CONVERT(BIGINT, [Field_C])), '') +
COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),[Field_D],20), ''));
GO
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score -1):

Someone once said you can add an apostrophe character to the beginning of the long number data for excel to ignore them.

The only other thing I've found to work is a setting buried in the options that stops autoformatting documents based on perceived data types.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/undo-or-turn-off-automatic-formatting-HA102491299.aspx

Unfortunately, the latter is user-specific.  If you send the file to another user who doesn't have that option turned off, he will see the same garbage data.

Comment: Problem with scientific notion when importing from excel is well described in this post: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ccedd788-21d8-476c-9be3-f5a1aab07c09/scientific-notation-while-taking-data-from-excel-into-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

However, as posted before, I have solved it by importing data from excel as FLOAT(24) or FLOAT(53), depending on the length of the long number field.

Comment: As for the conversion whithin SQL Server, I have just found new approach (str()) which might work as needed - I will check if it works when I get to the computer I have SQL Server on, see link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521354/convert-float-into-varchar-in-sql-server-without-scientific-notation)

Thanks for input provided. I hope approach I posted above works for conversion, and FLOAT->NVARCHAR will no longer be an issue; outer join is the main problem anyways, nowhere in the net can I find an example with duplicating common fields;