# While inserting long integer values in mysql database in it always round up number

Tags: php

I have tried to insert integer like `356361070084127` in mysql table named `IMEI`. However, while inserting it from excel file it convert these `IMEI` automatically to `356361070084120` changing last digit to `0`. I have used `PHPExccel` to upload the excel file.

Comment: Check database column type and max integer that it can hold.

Comment: I have used the bigint in my mysql database too. But it didnot help either.

Comment: Make it unsigned and try.

Comment: making it unsigned also didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Actually I want these numbers to store IMEI no. Is there any option.

Comment: If you are not going to perform any mathematical operation on the no, then store it as a string in varchar column.

Comment: It shows in exponential form. How can remove the exponential form?

Comment: No idea.. Does it show in exponential form in a varchar column?

Comment: Yes friend. while inserting 999999999999999 value it shows 1.0E+15

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/exporting-csv-file-large-numbers-being-converted-to-exponent-format/24894/5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521354/convert-float-into-varchar-in-sql-server-without-scientific-notation

Comment: _"Actually I want these numbers to store IMEI no"_ - don't use a numeric data type for those - those aren't actual numbers. Store them as what they are - _strings_ that happen to consist of numeric digits only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Do a "select" in mysql to verify the "bigint" shows as expected in the database.
2. In "Excel":

   a) select one of the integer values

   b) Navigate to Home > Number

   c) Increase Decimal

I suspect the actual problem is that Excel might be converting the integer to floating point, then rounding the floating point value.

One way to prevent this is to store the value as a "string" instead of "integer" - that way you can store a decimal value that's arbitrarily long.

Here is some additional information:

https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/displaying-long-numbers-greater-than-15-char-in-excel-292538/

ADDENDUM:
If you want to store an [IMEI number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity) ... *THEN USE TYPE "STRING"*!  In the database, and ESPECIALLY in Excel!

Comment: Thanks paualsm4. Converting value to string in excel and bigint to varchat in mysql really solved the problem.