# change scientific notation in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns [supplier_code], [EAN] both as bigint.

For instance:

```
1. 1000 / 234562
2. 1001 / 332221
3. 1000 / 222221
```

The problem is when I use group concatenation it converts to scientific notation

```
 1. 1000 / 2.35E+05 and 2.22E+05
 2. 1001 / 2.22E+05
```

The result I want is

```
 1. 1000 / 234562 and 222221
 2. 1001 / 332221
```

Comment: *when I use group concatenation* show how you are doing it

Comment: This sounds more like a display question than an actual result question. What are you displaying this in?

Comment: SELECT
 [Supplier Code],
 [EAN] = master.dbo.GROUP_CONCAT_DS(DISTINCT [EAN], ' and ', 1)
INTO #ean
FROM ean

Comment: What is "group concatenation"?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT_DS` is not a standard function. Is it [this `GROUP_CONCAT_DS`](https://github.com/orlando-colamatteo/ms-sql-server-group-concat-sqlclr/blob/master/GroupConcat/GROUP_CONCAT_DS.cs)? Try explicitly `CONVERT`ing your source data to an `NVARCHAR` of the appropriate format first, before feeding it to the custom aggregate.

Comment: It looks like the output you're looking for is a string like '1000/234562, 222221' etc.  If that's the case, then [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/194887/2655263) doesn't require a third-party function; it becomes just a string concatenation thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert float into varchar in SQL server without scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521354/convert-float-into-varchar-in-sql-server-without-scientific-notation)

Comment: Use [`STR()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql) instead of casting to a varchar.  You may need to use `LTRIM(STR())`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have someone debug the code for that custom GROUP_CONCAT_DS function.

Or use standard T-SQL to do a group concat.

For example:

```
declare @TestEAN table (supplier_code bigint, EAN bigint);

insert into @TestEAN (supplier_code, EAN) values
(1000, 1234567890123456701),
(1000, 1234567890123456702),
(1001, 1234567890123456789);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpEAN') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpEAN;

SELECT supplier_code as [Supplier Code],
[EAN] = STUFF((
          SELECT ' and ' + cast(t2.EAN as varchar(30))
          FROM @TestEAN t2
          WHERE t.supplier_code = t2.supplier_code
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 5, '')
INTO #tmpEAN
FROM (
    select supplier_code
    from @TestEAN 
    group by supplier_code
) t;

select * from #tmpEAN;
```

Note that SQL Server 2017 includes a [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) function.