# what exactly precision of 15 digits mean for float data type?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

As per the [float and real (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) float is an approximate data type.

But also in the same article it is being mentioned that float has precision of 15 digits.

What exactly it mean by *Precision of 15 digits*?

Comment: Decimal digits. The floating point format allows for 53 significant binary digits. 53 * log(2) is just a bit under 16 which is where that number comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the first 15 digits are approximately correct. Thanks to IEEE 754 there are many  numbers that can't be exactly represented, but you can be sure that the first 15 digits are very close.

Comment: also good to note that a select query on float returns 15 digits if the number stored is that precise.

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers are exact with a precision of 15 digits. That means if you calculate something and store the outcome as a float, you can be sure the first 15 digits are the right result. After that they might (and usually are) not.