# How does convert(varchar, float) decide how many decimal places to keep?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got `32040.6` for `select CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(32040.5742 as float))`

Why does it keep only one decimal places by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why casting from float to varchar is being rounded in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512046/why-casting-from-float-to-varchar-is-being-rounded-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Joe I read that question, and used ``str``. But I'm curious how the rounding actually works for float.

Comment: look at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx  For example, you can get scientific notation with more precision by using `select CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(32040.5742 as float), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select ltrim(STR( cast(32040.5742 as float),10,4  ))
```

or perhaps better still:

```
select FORMAT( cast(32040.5742 as float), '########0.####');
```

please note the 0 in the format here has a specific meaning, for details, please read:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings