# How do I convert a float to varchar without loss of decimal places? SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012: converting a `float` to `varchar` is removing decimal places.

For example:

```
select convert(varchar, cast(834.7833 as float))
```

returns a `varchar` with `834.783`.

How do I convert a `float` to `varchar` without loss of decimal places?

This is a similar question to this unanswered question:

[How does convert(varchar, float) decide how many decimal places to keep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469991/how-does-convertvarchar-float-decide-how-many-decimal-places-to-keep)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to do a `CAST(... AS FLOAT)` at all??

Try these snippets - they return the full number of decimal points:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 834.7833)

SELECT
    CAST(834.7833 AS VARCHAR(20))
```

Both of these output this result:

```
834.7833
```

Comment: Why do you need to do a CAST(... AS FLOAT) at all? Because the `834.7833` literal has a `decimal` type in SQL Server, not `float`. It may be important,