# converting float to varchar causes loss in values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think,i might have messed up some historical data..

my database has below value stored as `float(53)`.(dumped from SSIS)

```
  643478425
```

when we join this table,with other tables,i got type conversions..

so we altered above column value to `varchar(100)`,like below

```
alter table dbo.test
alter column colname varchar(100)
```

now ,all the above values (`643478425`) are now stored as

```
6.43478e+008
```

which is not i want..

I tried converting ,back to get original value.

I tried below

```
 select cast(6.43478e+008 as float(100))  --gives 643478000
```

which is not correct

any ideas

Below is how you can repro

```
 create table #test
     (
      id float(53)
      )

      insert into #test
      select '643478425'

      select * from #test

      alter table #test
      alter column id varchar(100)


      select * from #test
```

Comment: I don't think this can be revert. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes ,thinking the same,but waiting for any ideas

Comment: [this explains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512046/why-casting-from-float-to-varchar-is-being-rounded-in-sql-server) the issue with float precision, but as @SankarRaj said, i don't think you can revert it now without going to a backup.... which hopefully you have!

Comment: `6.43478e+008` means `6.43478 * 100000000` so you have already lost the last three that it can't be revert. unless you know `abraka dabra`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After converting it to `varchar`, you've lost the `float` precision, which you can't revert. Based on the documentation:

### [float and real (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173773.aspx)

> Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512046/why-casting-from-float-to-varchar-is-being-rounded-in-sql-server) suggests, when converting you can use:

### [STR (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189527.aspx)

> Returns character data converted from numeric data.

So rather than alter the column, create a new column and populate that like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE #test
    (
      id FLOAT(53) ,
      val NVARCHAR(100)
    );

 INSERT INTO #test
        ( id, val )
        SELECT  643478425 ,
                NULL;

 UPDATE #test
 SET    val = STR(id, 20, 0);

 SELECT *
 FROM   #test;

 DROP TABLE #test;
```

To get:

```
id          val
643478425   643478425
```

Comment: Thanks ,i have checked `STR`,after this

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the pig out of the sausage, TheGameiswar.

With the cast, you lost precision that you cannot get back again ...

The only chance you have is if you can get the data from SSIS again.

Then, to support the join you want: the data is numeric, and seems to be exactly at INTEGER precision, just from your example, at least.

I would convert the column to INTEGER or BIGINT and get the data from SSIS again. I would also convert the join columns from the other tables to INTEGERS: Always try to join on columns of the same type.

Alternatively, convert to INTEGER first, then to VARCHAR.

Comment: Thanks for the help