# SELECT vs UPDATE, Unexpected rounding when using ABS function

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point, numbers

Attached is a code sample to run in SQL. This seems like unexpected behavior for SQL Server. What should happen is to remove the negative from the number but when using the same function under the update command it does the absolute value and also rounds the number. Why is this?

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE (TEST varchar(2048));

INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES ('  -29972.95');

SELECT TEST FROM @TEST;

SELECT ABS(TEST) FROM @TEST;

UPDATE @TEST SET TEST = ABS(TEST);

SELECT TEST FROM @TEST;
```

Below are the results of that code.

```
  -29972.95
29972.95
29973
```

Comment: That's because the type of TEST is varchar.  If you use decimal(9, 2) instead then ABS return a decimal value

Comment: @Rono I think the real question is why does this rounding occur only in an UPDATE and not in a SELECT?

Comment: It may be interesting to note that the same occurs if you replace the `ABS(x)` function with the `ROUND(x,2)` function.

Comment: Cause your datatype is varchar. If it was a decimal, this wouldn't happen. Something is happening on the conversion. ABS returns a numeric datatype but the update of the varchar isn't happening as expected. Buy, if you change the datatype of your table, you'll see this behavior go away and this is why you should choose the correct datatypes when storing data

Comment: @scsimon WHY does using a varchar cause the engine to treat the results of a SELECT differently than the results of an UPDATE?

Comment: You get expected results if you use `-29972.9`. Weird.

Comment: @TabAlleman i said `Something is happening on the conversion`. If i knew what, I'd post it

Comment: Notice casting it correctly fixes the issue too... `UPDATE @TEST SET TEST = abs(cast(test as decimal(7,2)))` so the select is doing the implicit conversion correctly but the update isn't, it seems. Still, using numeric datatypes would fix the issue.

Comment: This is an implicit/default style of the `CONVERT` using style "0" for REAL/FLOAT (as returned by ABS) and is limited to 6 digits before silently truncating. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems more a "feature" of the `CONVERT` function than anything to do with `SELECT` or `UPDATE` (only reason it is different is because the `UPDATE` implicitly converts the `FLOAT(8)` returned by `ABS(...)` back into `VARCHAR`).

The compute scalar in the update plan contains the expression

```
[Expr1003] = Scalar Operator(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(2048),
                                              abs(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(float(53),[TEST],0))
                                              ,0) /*<-- style used for convert from float*/
                            )
```

> **Value - Output**
>
> 0 (default) - A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
>
> 1 - Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
>
> 2 - Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.

From MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

This can be seen in the example below:

```
SELECT
    [# Digits],
    CONVERT(FLOAT(8), CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), N)) AS [FLOAT(VARCHAR(N))],
    CONVERT(FLOAT(8), CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), N, 0)) AS [FLOAT(VARCHAR(N, 0))],
    CONVERT(FLOAT(8), CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), N, 1)) AS [FLOAT(VARCHAR(N, 1))]
FROM (SELECT '6 digits', ABS('9972.95') UNION ALL SELECT '7 digits', ABS('29972.95')) T ([# Digits], N)
```

This returns the following results:

```
# Digits FLOAT(VARCHAR(N)) FLOAT(VARCHAR(N, 0)) FLOAT(VARCHAR(N, 1))
-------- ----------------- -------------------- --------------------
6 digits 9972.95           9972.95              9972.95
7 digits 29973             29973                29972.95
```

This proves the `UPDATE` was using `CONVERT(VARCHAR, ABS(...))` effectively with the default style of "0". This limited the `FLOAT` from the `ABS` to 6 digits. Taking 1 character away so it does not overflow the implicit conversion, you retain the actual values in this scenario.

**Taking this back to the OP:**

- The `ABS` function in this case is returning a `FLOAT(8)` in the example.
- The `UPDATE` then caused an implicit conversion that was effectively `CONVERT(VARCHAR(2048), ABS(...), 0), which then overflowed the max digits of the default style.
- To get around this behavior (if this is related to a practical issue), you need to specify the style of 1 or 2 (or even 3 to get 17 digits) to avoid this truncation (but be sure to handle the scientific notation used since it is now always returned in this case)

Comment: Thanks Martin. Nice find from the plan.

Answer (score 1):

(some preliminary testing deleted for brevity)

It definitely has to do with silent truncating during INSERT/UPDATEs.

If you change the value insertion to this:

```
INSERT INTO @TEST SELECT ABS('  -29972.95')
```

You immediately get the same rounding/truncation without doing an UPDATE.

Meanwhile, `SELECT ABS('  -29972.95')` produces expected results.

Further testing supports the theory of an implicit float conversion, and indicates that the culprit lies with the conversion back to varchar:

```
DECLARE @Flt float = '  -29972.95'

SELECT @Flt;

SELECT CAST(@Flt AS varchar(2048))
```

Produces:

```
-29972.95

-29972
```

**Probably final edit:**

I was sniffing up the same tree as Martin.  [I found this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7b2226b1-8d88-405c-9997-a7f02bc69021/float-to-varchar-retaining-decimal-places?forum=sqlexpress).

Which made me try this:

```
DECLARE @Flt float = '  -29972.95'

SELECT @Flt;

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(2048),@Flt,128)
```

Which produced this:

```
-29972.95

-29972.95
```

So I'm gonna call this *kinda documented* since the 128 style is a legacy style that is deprecated and may go away in a future release.   But none of the currently documented styles produce the same result.  Very interesting.

Comment: Why would it truncate with `varchar(2048)`? Seems plenty large enough to hold the 12 or so characters in the string.

Comment: @scsimon - the default style for `CONVERT` is `0` (`A maximum of 6 digits`)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. Presumably the number is rounded to 6 which leaves 5 in this case as `95` rounds up to `00`

Comment: That’s more clear @MartinSmith and should be the answer 

Comment: It seems to have to do with scientific notation.   Look what happens when you start adding more and more digits to the left of the decimal in the hard-coded entry.

Comment: So the varchar value is being assigned a converted decimal value in the update statement and that conversion uses the default sql server data type conversion rules which rounds the value, furthermore, this default conversion is not performed during the select as no type conversion is needed, sound plausible? ...another reason why its a good idea to convert to numeric types to perform mathematical operations.

Comment: Although it still doesn't document the "why", this question has some useful insight, especially the STR() function.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512046/why-casting-from-float-to-varchar-is-being-rounded-in-sql-server

Comment: I dont understand why you are still looking for the "Why". you can see in the execution plan the implicit convert uses style 0. The behaviour of style 0 is documented and explains the behaviour in the question.

Comment: You're right, I've gone around in too many circles researching this and forgot which direction I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

[`ABS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is supposed to operate on numeric values and varchar input is converted to float. Most likely explanation for this behavior is that float has [highest precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) among all numeric data types such as decimal, int, bit.

Your `SELECT` statement simply returns the float result. However the `UPDATE` statement **implicitly** converts the float back to varchar producing unexpected results:

```
SELECT
    test,
    ABS(test) AS test_abs,
    CAST(ABS(test) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS test_abs_str
FROM (VALUES
    ('-29972.95'),
    ('-29972.94'),
    ('-29972.9')
) AS test(test)

test      | test_abs | test_abs_str
----------|----------|-------------
-29972.95 | 29972.95 | 29973
-29972.94 | 29972.94 | 29972.9
-29972.9  |  29972.9 | 29972.9
```

I would suggest that you use explicit conversion and exact numeric datatype to avoid this and other potential problems with implicit conversions / floats:

```
SELECT
    test,
    ABS(CAST(test AS DECIMAL(18, 2))) AS test_abs,
    CAST(ABS(CAST(test AS DECIMAL(18, 2))) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS test_abs_str
FROM (VALUES
    ('-29972.95'),
    ('-29972.94'),
    ('-29972.9')
) AS test(test)

test      | test_abs | test_abs_str
----------|----------|-------------
-29972.95 | 29972.95 | 29972.95
-29972.94 | 29972.94 | 29972.94
-29972.9  | 29972.90 | 29972.90
```

Answer (score 0):

ABS is a mathematical function, that means is designed to work with numeric values, you cannot expect a proper behavior of the function when using other data types like in this case VARCHAR, I suggest first to do the required CAST to a numeric data type before applying the ABS function as follows:

```
UPDATE @TEST SET TEST = ABS(CAST(TEST AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
```

After this your query will output

> 29972.95

This does not solve how it is posible that ABS works fine when selecting and not when updating a value, maybe it is a bug on sqlserver but also it is a really bad practice to avoid casting to proper data types required by functions. Maybe an implicit cast occurs when a SELECT clause is performed but ignored on UPDATE because microsoft is expecting you to do the right thing.