# SQL Server truncating values of a whole number in a float field when cast to CHAR

Tags: sql-server, casting, floating-point, rounding

I have a rather strange problem.

Due to sourcing one column in a large query from both `FLOAT` and `CHAR` columns I'm casting the resulting `FLOAT` to `CHAR` so that the data types for the resulting query match.

For a minority of values of whole numbers in the `FLOAT` column, it is truncating the whole number to scientific notation which is losing one whole number.

Example

```
DECLARE @fl FLOAT
SET @fl = 1041931

SELECT CAST(ISNULL(@fl, '0') AS VARCHAR(20))
```

This is displaying

```
1.04193+e006
```

Which when expanded is 1041930 hence losing the last digit.

What am I doing wrong to display whole numbers correctly? This doesn't happen for FLOATS with decimals.

Comment: Very weird, and I don't know the answer, but a possible solution is using `str` e.g. `STR(ISNULL(@fl, '0.0'), 25, 0)`

Comment: Well that indeed does work, weirdly. It pads with space though maybe I can use LEN to only take the filled FLOAT space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why casting from float to varchar is being rounded in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512046/why-casting-from-float-to-varchar-is-being-rounded-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
DECLARE @fl FLOAT
SET @fl = 1041931
SELECT CAST(CAST(ISNULL(@fl, '0') AS DECIMAL(10,0)) AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Comment: That is too difficult to handle when I have 4 decimal places and none in the same field.